# Is there a cap on daily up/downvotes?

Tags: support, voting

Is there a cap on the number of times I can up/downvote other people's questions and answers in a day?

Comment: Wasn't the FAQ migrated over here? I can't find it.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits-in-stackoverflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can vote 30 times a day. This applies to all the sites and is a grand total of 30 up and down votes.

I tried to find it listed on the site, but not having luck finding it.

Answer (score 4):

The cap(s) I believe are:

- Voting up and down: 30 times per day
- Voting to close and reopen: 12 times per day
- Flagging a post as Spam or Offensive: 5 times per day

Unsure on the limits for comment voting.

Comment: I believe you get 5 flags per day, and as far as I can tell you get 17280 comment votes

Comment: Shortly after comment voting was introduced, I did run out of comment votes. But word is the limit has since been removed. I haven't tested it, though.

Comment: @mmyers: No, there is definitely a limit.  I hit it just last week, during the wave of people posting crazy gibberish.

Comment: I definitely hit comment threshold last week