# What is the daily comment vote limit?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-voting

I just ran out and it feels like I used maybe 10-15 (could've been 20). It seems low if so.

Answer (score 34):

From the blog:

> [Each user gets 5 comment flag votes, and 30 comment upvotes, per day.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/comments-now-with-flags-and-votes/)

Note that the comment flag vote limits have changed since that blog post; the post and comment flags limits are now combined, [and the limit is determined by your reputation and flagging history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185888/on-the-recent-changes-to-flagging-and-limits/185890#185890).

Comment: And lo, you cannot use all of your comment flag votes on one comment. No matter how much you yell, "Die! Die you bastard!" Trust me, I've tried.

Comment: Additionally, comment upvotes are not refunded if the post they were attached to gets deleted.

Comment: @Ren, I was gonna vote for that comment. That makes for a nice suggested feature.