# Survivor question badge?

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

I think there is a value in those questions that are closed but later are re-opened because of popular demand.

Should these questions have some type of survivor/popular badge? Those ones when the community decides that it is worth to make an exception to the rules

Comment: Maybe a 10 point rep gain, but I don't think it warrants a new badge

Comment: Not many mods have the spine required to vote to reopen a closed question. It is like the SO equivalent of breaking the picket line. The few that do should get the badge.

Comment: @Evan, you mean 3ks, that's all it takes to vote to reopen

Comment: @Even: Actually the majority of the time there isn't a reason to reopen. It has nothing to do with *spine*.

Comment: I would upvote @Josh and @Lance, but I'm out of comment votes for the day. @Evan, stop whining that your off topic questions get closed!!!

Comment: @Evan: I've voted to reopen on many an occasion. Not nearly as often as I vote to close, but it does happen. But I never vote to reopen off-topic material; perhaps that is the issue you are dealing with?

Comment: @Josh: You can run out of comment votes!?!?

Comment: @Josh: Yes, you can! happens to me all the time on Meta :-)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18994/what-is-the-daily-comment-vote-limit

Comment: @Josh: Good to know, I never noticed. Come back when you have fresh votes! :)

Comment: @Josh Overflow.

Answer (score 13):

Some kind of reward would seem to indicate that these types of questions somehow have *more* value than other types of questions.  The reality is that a significant portion of the community thinks they have *less*.

Comment: Very good point.

Comment: But is this what SO is suppose to promote? The community is the one to decide. If one question is voted several times to be kept open, that means that a significant portion of the community do think that the question has a special value that should allow an exception

Comment: @Francisco: In order for a question to be voted open several times, it must also be voted closed several times.  Which do you think the community values more, a question that is voted closed several times or a question that is never closed at all?

Comment: I don't think we have to necessarily *discourage* potentially controversial questions, but I don't think they should be rewarded with a special badge either.

Answer (score 8):

Then we'd have a competition of people trying to create borderline questions.

**Oh the inhumanity.**

Comment: I think the quote is "Oh the humanity" :)

Comment: @web: Errr... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42919/my-calm-rational-assessment-of-the-question-upvote-rep-gain-change-and-ensuing-g/42944#42944

Comment: @Jon - That was excellent +1

Comment: @web, the original quote was with 'humanity', but an often used paraphrase is with 'inhumanity' (35,800 google hits) (and I thought it fit better here).

Comment: @Lance - I figured, i was just giving you a hard time.

Comment: @web, hard time accepted :)