# 'Daily vote limit reached' only for comments

Tags: support, comments, answers, voting, voting-limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the daily comment vote limit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18994/what-is-the-daily-comment-vote-limit)

I'm not completely sure but when I want to vote a comment I get the message:

```
Daily vote limit reached; vote again in 10 hours
```

but for answers I can still vote.

Does this mean there is a separate limit for comment votes and answer votes? If so, from my point of view it would be a nice idea if the message was written more precisely.

Comment: @YOU: Perhaps that's for answers - because I'm not having problems with voting for answers.

Comment: ah, haha, I missed the comment part :P I thought you were talking about questions vote vs answer votes.

Comment: Not a duplicate; that one is "what's the limit," this one is "if I understand the message correctly, its wording should be improved."

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are two different limits: There is a daily limit for votes on posts, and there is a daily limit for votes on comments.

The limit on comment votes is reported on [Comments: Now with Flags and Votes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/comments-now-with-flags-and-votes/).

> Each user gets 5 comment flag votes, and 30 comment upvotes, per day.

The error message could be misunderstood, and interpreted as saying that you cannot vote anymore on comments and posts.
Probably the message should report which daily limit has been reached. In that way, users would not take the assumption it means they cannot vote anymore for that day. The problem is when you have also reached the daily limit for post votes, and you think there is a daily limit for votes that includes both the votes on posts, and on comments. (It actually happened to me, and I thought I could vote for comments as long as I still had votes for posts to cast.)

Comment: Thanks for that quote - that's quite to the point :)