# Mention comment voting limits in Help Center (on vote up privilege page)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, help-center, voting-limits

Some day before I was searching for suggestions I have in mind here on Meta and voting on existing posts, mostly on comments. By the end of the day I've got a message:

> Daily vote limit reached; vote again in X hours.

I then went to my profile to check the votes count (through a badge progress) and it was nowhere near the limit:
[image: Message vs. votes count]

---

It's unclear that votes on comments have a separate limit (or that they have one at all). It's [mentioned in FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/578924) of course, but why would someone go check the FAQ if they've [already been told about the limits in Help Center](/help/privileges/vote-up) and remember them? And it's still not mentioned anywhere that votes on comments do not count towards the Suffrage and Vox Populi badges.

Suggestions:

1. Please mention all the above on [vote up privilege page](/help/privileges/vote-up).
   You could add just a few phrases, like "**Votes on comments are counted separately**" and "There are several badges you can receive for voting **on questions and answers**:";
2. [Message texts could be improved as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96147/578924). Please tell exactly which limit was reached.

Comment: While I think putting *all* the information about voting limits that's in the FAQ on the privilege page may be a bit much (linking 'you have a limited number of votes' to that FAQ page seems a better idea to me, to avoid very, very, very long help center pages), improving the badges to make it clearer they're about voting on posts and improving the messages sounds like a good plan to me :)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I don't mean putting _all_ the info from that FAQ. =)) But the privilege page already mention post limits and badges, so you could add just a few phrases, like "**Votes on comments are counted separately**" and "There are several badges you can receive for voting **on questions and answers**:". Linking to FAQ is always welcome of course.

Comment: It doesn't help that the factoids about comment voting on that help center page are intermingled with the facts about post voting. There are some minor changes here that will likely help. The page is focused on the post upvoting, so the comments even being mentioned is a bit of a side point, could probably have a new section that briefly mentions "You can also upvote comments. These are counted separately from post votes and don't impact badge progression".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've overhauled the [help center article a bit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up), hoping to make the differences between post and comment votes different. I agree that the warning text for using all comment votes could also benefit from an update - "Daily comment vote limit reached; vote again in n hours." and I'll be sending that to the devs' backlog to work on as part of bug duty.

Comment: A few notes: 1. "What happens when I vote up comments?" section should answer the question first; 2. There's too much repetition, about rep and badges in particular (okay, I've got it now =)) ). Consider the following changes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cd47.png (sorry, can't post this as a text...)

Comment: It would be nice to update the message for posts as well, for consistency.

Comment: I've adjusted the article a bit to address your concerns. I was mentioning it a bit more than strictly necessary - my thinking was that many people only read the sections they care about but it's a short page as it is. My request to change the warning text does mention that it makes sense to change the post voting warning.

Answer (score 7):

I've updated this string - it now clarifies between comment vote limit and post vote limit. The fix for this will be live within the next day or so. Thanks for reporting!