# Could I get warned when nearing the end of my daily comment-vote ration?

Tags: feature-request, comment-voting, voting-limits

There have been a couple days when I hit the end of my comment-votes.  (I don't even know how many I get per day - 20?)  I thought it could be made less abrupt, as in post-voting.

I'm sure someone has already thought of this, and maybe there is a reason why there isn't a warning, but since no one has already proposed it here, I am doing so.

Comment: I had no idea there was a comment vote limit.

Comment: You must be sane.

Comment: I just make a little mark on the wall of my cell with a rock when I make a comment.  Works for regular votes, too.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18994/what-is-the-daily-comment-vote-limit - 30 comment votes

Comment: I hit it a lot on Meta. Never on SO. There's no warning because comment votes are intended to be used sparingly to highlight the *very best comments* that should always be displayed.