# Increase daily comment votes and flags limit

Tags: feature-request, comment-flags, comment-voting, voting-limits

I just got the "Daily vote limit reached"-message. I was just about to up-vote a great comment, but now I've got to wait for 10 hours, and that's just plain stupid.
As [this blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/comments-now-with-flags-and-votes/) shows, a user has got 30 comment-votes and 5 comment-flags per day. In my opinion, this is not enough at all, especially not for active users like myself. There are plenty of abusive comments to be flagged and great comments to be upvoted, and I would very much like to be able to upvote all of them!

Could we up the standard limit to 50 votes and 10 flags for all users, and let users with more than 2000 rep get the double (100 votes and 20 flags)?

Comment: What I'd rather have is the ability to undo accidental comment votes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On the recent changes to flagging and limits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185888/on-the-recent-changes-to-flagging-and-limits)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work), the number of comment flags you get increases with a combination of higher reputation and flag weight. (Don't know what the cap is, but it's above 50.)
So that's already implemented, and higher than what you suggest.

As for comment votes, well, comments aren't all that important. You need limits in the same way you need limits for normal post (Q&A) votes (see [Why are there voting limits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28314/why-are-there-voting-limits) for instance). I don't see how adding an extra 20 or 70 comment votes per day would increase the overall quality of the sites – comments already get plenty of votes as it is in my opinion.

Try to focus more on the actual questions and answers, those are the important parts of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

If a single question/answer can have multiple comments, it would be logical to give higher comment vote limit, for example 80.

As alternative, if you vote on question/answer, you get **1 free vote** on comment/question to that answer. If you're encouraged (at least by downvoting) to leave a comment why you think that question/answer is bad, the vote to comment explaining that has the same effect, therefore you should be allowed to do that for free.