# Increase daily voting limits depending on reputation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, up-votes, review, voting-limits

I'm facing an issue, quite often debated (like in [Why are there voting limits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28314/why-are-there-voting-limits) and like the 4 firs page I found about vote up limit) : **I am feeling really restricted by vote up limit**.

*Please, read the below explanations before downvote (which would probably happen for some of you)*

### Background

There is a few days ago, I was still accepting that the limit was a real need ... there were some stupid users that wrote script for automatic voting, this is a great responsibility (thanks to Spiderman ;D), etc.
I quickly and easily earned Civic Duty badge (at least easily on SO ;)), and I found that the limit was reasonable.

But since the new reviewing functionality checks that you don't have reached the maximum upvotes (for first posts), I can't reward really good question and review posts at the same time. I read some fantastic answers about software versioning with Maven, that should be top rated for the rest or their electronics life ( ;) ) ... and I could not promote them !

**I feel, now, I'm enough experienced on Stack Exchange to be respectful and "narrow"**, at least really more than I voted up for the first time :).

### Proposal

So, I think now (due to reviewing module at least), vote up limit should be increased with different caps, like :

- +1 more vote by day, every 1k reputation limited to 5 or 10 times
- +2 more vote by day, (maybe +5) with civic duty badge
- +? more vote by day, (with every reviewer badge depending on its value (+1 for custodian + 2 for reviewer)
- +5 more vote by day, (maybe +10) with electorate badge

Those limits are obviously examples and should be reviewed too.
I hope you will help me to design reasonable rule.

Comment: He is not asking about recieving, but rather about the ability to give additional upvotes past the current daily limit

Comment: @azuflame sorry, I read +1, +2, +5 as rep increase, not vote counts. Still, I think this would be a very complicated algorithm for the software to monitor... and also seems to contradict the reason we have limits in the first place (to limit the amount of time you spend on the site).

Comment: So people with more rep get to spend more rep? I believe this is rather skewing the (already unbalanced) system of a few users who vote a lot and the rest which basically doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple solution now, with the **saves** (replaced bookmarks) functionality.

Create two saves lists "Vote Up" and "Vote Down". When you stumble upon a post you wish to vote, but have already expended your daily vote count, add it to the proper list.

Daily work through the review queues you wish, using some amount of votes as needed. Then finish your remaining votes for the day with the saves and un-save those you have registered your vote.

I use this system, it works well.

Answer (score -7):

I agree with you. I have found these reasons:

Cons:

- Allows the more experienced users on Meta and other sites to voice their opinions on more matters than are currently possible
- Allows the community to show greater appreciation to the well-thought answers and questions
- Allows the larger members of the community to have a slightly larger voice than the people who just log on once or twice a week

Pros:

- If SO does this to upvotes, they would have to alter thier rep systems, auto-flag systems(for 'power-upvotes' (can't remember the term))
- They would most likely make these harder to get as you go on, and more people would go on these sites more and more, creating addictions (or furthering current ones)

This is community wiki, so add what you think this would do to the community.

Comment: I think this should be posted as two separate answers. How can I up-vote an answer that lists both pros and cons?

Comment: That's not really how community wiki works, for example I disagree that some of your "pros" points are actually pros. Should I just remove them?

Comment: You rearrange them as you see fit, if it's community wiki

Comment: That'll only lead to multiple people editing the same post as they see fit, which results in edits overwriting each other and people rolling back to versions they prefer. Post individual positions as separate posts and let people vote on these instead.

Comment: @azulflame I've re-arranged them (sorry, couldn't resist ;)