# Daily limits on voting

Tags: feature-request, voting

Are the number of daily votes each user gets always fixed regardless of reputation? Users with increasing reputation are clearly spending more time on the site, and sometimes the lack of votes can by annoying. I have experienced that a lot in the past few weeks.

**Edit**: I am mostly concerned with not being able to upvote good questions and answers, of which there are many in a day.

Comment: Please explain better I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Lance, I feel the quotas for daily vote limits are too low.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits

Answer (score 6):

The number of daily votes is the same for every user.

I don't necessarily agree that high rep users spend more time on the site...

Comment: They work *smarter*, not harder!

Comment: We spend more time *on Meta* ;) (Not that I consider myself a high rep user...)

Comment: I love meta, way more fun imo @voy, SO is too serious =)

Comment: @voyager: spend time? Sounds more like wasting to me ;-)

Comment: I've always been intrigued by the concept of meta - questions about questions :P .. @Downvoter, I am not saying that those users aren't smart or geniuses, but if people have answered 100-200+ questions, then they are clearly enjoying SO which keeps them coming back.

Comment: @Ivo: it's only a waste if you don't get anything out of it :P

Answer (score 4):

High-rep users have no more influence on the reputation of others than low-rep users do. This is by design.

Comment: I wouldn't want a stringent hierarchical society either, but it seems like I'm always running out of votes nowadays. And I'm not a liberal voter by any means. Maybe the cap is too low or I am spending too much time on the site now.