# What is the vote system like here?

Tags: discussion, voting

I'm experiencing some confusion.
Can a user vote both up and down on a specific post? How about different answers to one question? (I am a newbie, so I can't test; no reputation.)

I would greatly appreciate it if someone would provide some info about the vote-flow design.

Comment: Read the faq : http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I was going to close this as a duplicate, but I actually can't find another question asking about this aspect of the voting system. So, I moved my previous comment to an [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65351/what-is-the-vote-system-like-here/65354#65354).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone vote both up and down at the specific post?

Yes and no, depending on what you mean. If you vote down an answer, but then it gets edited and you think it got better and deserves an upvote, you can change your vote. You can't *simultaneously* vote a post up and down however (that obviously doesn't make sense.)

> How about the posts of same question?

If you mean answers to the same question, absolutely. If you think an answer is good, and another one is bad, vote one up and the other one down. This is fundamentally how Stackoverflow works; let voting make the best answer float to the top.

Answer (score 1):

@user151569, welcome to Meta Stack Overflow! Basically, for every post, you can choose exactly one of the following three options:

- vote up
- vote down
- not vote at all

Each option has slightly different reputation requirements. In general, you cannot undo or change your vote. There are two exceptions:

- immediately after you vote, you can undo/change; this is in case you clicked the vote button by accident
- if the post is edited, you can undo/change; this is in case the edit changed something that you previously agreed/disagreed with

For more detail, see the community-generated FAQ [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits-in-stackoverflow). The community-generated FAQ is **not** the same as the site FAQ that you were shown earlier.

You can vote for each question and each answer completely independently. You cannot have multiple votes on one post at the same time.