# Could there be a warning that the answer vote limit is nearing?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, voting-limits

I was browsing around [photo se](https://photo.stackexchange.com/), reading and voting some quality answers and suddenly got greeted by this:

> Come back to vote on more answers in 10 hours, or use your 10 remaining question votes now

Previously I've had warnings when I reach the total daily vote limit, but this came out of nowhere.

I still do get a warning when I have 5 (or less) question votes left. **Should there be a similar notification for answer votes?**

A side question: is this a new feature? Didn't see any mention in the [vote limits FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits).

Comment: It is a new feature, I coded it and deployed it today

Comment: @waffles oh, it's *that* new. I would probably had given it more time if I knew that.

Comment: and most important of all, thank you for exhausting your votes :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, the warnings are now back and work as they always did.

also see: [Please don't require answer votes to be cast before question votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes)

Comment: Good points in the other question. Seeing the overall process (at any time) sounds more reasonable than having a "Hold your horses! 5 answer votes left!" notification popping up; which would, though, be more *worry-free* than the current "Too bad you didn't count how many votes you've used, they're all gone now! See you in 10 hours (or maybe vote some questions)."