# Answers/questions votes cast rules

Tags: support, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please don't require answer votes to be cast before question votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes)

How are daily allowed votes separated between answers and questions?

I've just used 30 votes of my allowed 40 ones today. Most of them were on questions. Even though, I am now obligated to use all of my remaining votes on more questions and restricted from voting on answers.

The rules of daily votes separating is still ambiguous to me. I have read that the last 10 votes each day must always be on questions. Isn't better if there was a minimum votes cast per day for questions/answers?

Comment: You ask why it's like this, or do you ask for a change?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: I am not sure I understand those rulescompletely . However, if those rules say that the last 10 votes each day must be only on question, then I think that they need some refinement ..

Comment: OK, so you better change the tags to "feature-request", that's why I asked. :)

Comment: [Already requested, and there's hope.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New behavior:

1. Everyone gets a total of 30 votes.
2. You may up to 10 extra question votes.
3. Warnings remains simple ... (5 vote remaining, 4 vote remaining ...)
4. Question votes may be cast at any time during the day. However once you reach the N votes remaining warnings, stuff is set in stone. A question voting spree at the end will still count down.

See: [Please don't require answer votes to be cast before question votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes)