# What is "10 additional "question-only" daily votes"?

Tags: discussion, daily-reputation-limit, voting

Jeff said that Stack Overflow added 10 additional "question-only" daily votes ([This Blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)), and total votes limitation increased to 40.

But I voted 30 times in meta.stackoverflow.com today, then SO told me "daily vote limit reached". Even I voted on question, the prompt still pop up.

Where are the additional "question-only" daily votes?

How the "additional "question-only" daily votes" works?

Comment: See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90378/answers-questions-votes-cast-rules) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Separate vote pools for questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89534/separate-vote-pools-for-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to vote questions first before you hit the limit, but looks like you voted on answers today.

And actually limit increased to 40, and you voted 30 today, according to your vote stats on your profile.