# Why voting limit reduced from 40 to 30 for me?

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow, voting, vote-count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any voting limits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits)

I was doing review on Stack Overflow. And I have voted 30 times a day. Now when I was voting one question, popup for vote limit reached is came out. Although I was able to vote 40 times one day.

Then why I am not able to vote more than 30 times now?

Comment: @lunboks: I want to vote on questions. 10 additional votes are for questions according to your link. Then why not I am able to vote on questions.

Comment: It's a *maximum* of 10 extra votes. If you only vote on answers, you get zero extra votes.

Comment: Where it's written?

Comment: ... you have me there. I know I know it, but I'm not sure how I know it. Someone needs to track down a definitive source of how the bonus votes work and add that to the FAQ post. [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes/90256#90256) and its comments are a start, though.

Comment: Meanwhile I've enhanced that duplicate/FAQ, @lunboks and Somnath. (Oh, and only now I see you linked that very answer, lunboks...!)

Comment: I wrote a detailed explanation of this once, but it's hard to find because it's attached to the "voted 40 times" badge's entry [here, in the badge description FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/131713).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an additional 10 votes available to you for **questions only**.  Essentially you can vote 30 times a day + an additional 10 on questions.

Its all detailed within the [Voting section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits) of the  FAQ

Quoting from the linked faq entry -

> - Maximum 30 all-purpose votes per day per user (up or down)
>
>   - Maximum 10 additional question-only votes per day per user

Comment: But I want to vote on question though I am not able to same?

Comment: You can't vote on questions?

Comment: Why? 10 additional votes are for questions according to [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits). Then why not I am able to vote on questions?

Comment: see [@lunboks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128610/why-voting-limit-reduced-from-40-to-30-for-me/128611#comment351143_128610) explanation...