# How many votes have I cast on answers today?

Tags: feature-request, support, voting, vote-count

We can understand total number of votes on questions and answers differently from joining.

Is there any way to know the total number of votes I've cast on answers today?

I don't want to vote only 30 times on answers. Because of that I was not able to vote on questions after voting 30 times. See this question: [Why voting limit reduced from 40 to 30 for me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128610/why-voting-limit-reduced-from-40-to-30-for-me)

Comment: I do believe when you start approaching the cap for answers, it gives you a notice that you are voting on too many answers and you should consider voting on questions too.

Comment: @animuson:I was doing review of answers. I don't even remember I have done voting on questions too last day. Notice was not giving clear cut info about vote limit. I thought if necessary I can vote on questions in last 10 votes. But I was unable to do the same after voting 30 times. I might have voted on 1 to 2 questions. But there is no any proof. It's hard to vote by remembering vote count.

Answer (score 2):

Click your name and scroll to the bottom.  Look to the right - you'll see your votes cast stats.  Looks like you have cast 6 today.  It doesn't break it down by questions & answers.

[image]

Comment: That's why feature request is made by me.

Answer (score 0):

[Your user account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1045444/somnath-muluk) reports how much votes you casted during the UTC day, but it doesn't say how much of them were for answers, or for questions. If you remember the number of votes you casted for questions, and answers at the end of the previous UTC day, you can know how much votes you already casted for questions, and answers.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's very hard to vote by remembering vote count. Isn't that possible to give vote cast on questions and answers today?