# Didn't earn vox populi

Tags: support, badges, voting

In Stack overflow within searching my problems solution I finished my total no of voted ie 40 vote and this is two times but it is still not showing in my badges why ??

Comment: What feature request are you proposing here?

Comment: where is my badge I am requesting for that featured badge...

Comment: Just a note that you should be careful of not upvoting everything you see for a badge -- upvotes are meant for quality content that you have found useful and/or it is clear and well written.

Comment: I am going to upvote and I see that my votes are almost finished of the daya limit and then I found that there is a badge for use your all votes

Comment: Your many of Upvotes my be on answers. It is require to upvote atleast 10 question among your 40 votes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is because you've not used all the 40 votes for the day even once, which is the requirement for [*Vox Populi*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1108/vox-populi).

> Used the maximum 40 votes in a day.

[image: Vox Populi]

Doing the simple math, you've used 38 for today, which means you've used 37 in the past whole week barring today. And that leaves with 31 for the remaining month. You've not used all the 40 votes in a single day, and thus you've not been awarded with the badge.

Do note that you're allowed to vote 40 times in a day as long as you make sure 10 of those votes are on questions before you get the warning about only have a few votes left for the day as mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90256/216721).

Comment: Then why I am messaged to vote after somehow 11 hours

Comment: @Shrawan - Check the edit in my answer :) You get the full 40 votes for the day only if you vote on 10 questions before you start getting that warning.