# What does "Q only votes can't be used after 25 votes cast on answers" mean?

Tags: support, voting, rate-limiting

> 30 votes per day +10 for questions only (Q only votes can't be used after 25 votes cast on answers)

In [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide/164900#164900), here's the explanation for the votes. But although I try my best, I still can't understand what does "Q only votes can't be used after 25 votes cast on answers" mean. Does it mean if a user casts 25 votes on answers, so he can only cast 30 votes today not another 15 votes on questions?

Comment: Rate limit guide updated with the source, cheers! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard What does "timer resets" mean in rare limit guide, Sir?

Comment: It means that if for example I now post comment, then try to post again after 10 seconds, it will say I can post comment every 15 seconds. But then if I try again after 10 seconds (total 20 seconds after creating the first comment) **it will still show the error**, meaning each time I *try* to post comment, the timer is reset.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for you explanation. SE is truly awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly.

When a user starts using up their votes, the system eventually pops up a warning to the effect of "you only have X votes remaining", starting when they have five left. Once someone has voted on 25 answers, it needs to start popping that warning up, even though they might (without this rule) be able to vote another fifteen times. So, to keep things simple, once that message has popped up (i.e. you cast 25 votes on answers), Stack Exchange simply removes any remaining Q-only votes you could otherwise cast.

It wasn't always this way; see [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes) for some of the history behind the ten question-only votes.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean if a user casts 25 votes on answers, so he can only cast 30 votes today not another 15 votes on questions?

That's exactly what it means. If you cast 25 votes on answers and none on questions, you only have 30 votes that day. Every question vote done before reaching 25 votes bumps up the limit up to 40.

See [Waffles's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles) [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90256/) for more details.