# Why do we need both the Suffrage and Vox Populi badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

The Suffrage badge is awarded for using 30 votes in the day, and the Vox Populi for using 40.

I understand from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90479/whats-the-difference-between-suffrage-and-vox-populi-badge) that the idea of Vox Populi is to incentivise voting on questions, but is there any evidence that having two badges does so better than just having Vox Populi?

Comment: Assuming Vox Populi is newer then perhaps there was a desire not to depreciate an existing badge

Comment: More badges, mo' happy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suffrage is an older badge, and it existed for a couple of years before Vox Populi. You can get Suffrage by voting on 30 answers only. You *must* vote on questions to get Vox Populi, so it does incentivize question votes.  To your point, since you can get the two badges for casting the same 40 votes, the Suffrage badge doesn't really add anything. It's still around because badges are rarely (if ever?) revoked.

Comment: I see! So if I wanted to suggest that the Suffrage badge be deprecated (like the Analytical badge), would I need to ask another Meta question?

Comment: @kmoe Yes, it would be best to separate the feature request from the discussion. (Mostly because a new question will typically get more attention than an edited one.)