# Shouldn't Suffrage and Vox Populi be part of the same badge family?

Tags: discussion, badges

In looking over the [available badges](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/badges), I noticed [Suffrage](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/badges/57/suffrage) (bronze level) and [Vox Populi](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/badges/66/vox-populi) (also bronze level) are very similar. Shouldn't they be grouped in to the same badge-family?

> **Suffrage:** Used 30 votes in a day
>
> **Vox Populi:** Used the maximum 40 votes in a day

In a related note, if the max votes/day is 40, shouldn't Vox Populi be a gold level badge?

This is of course, just from a logical data standpoint - if a badge levels (bronze/silver/gold) have additional requirements beyond just being various stages of a type of interaction, perhaps the entire above argument is irrelevant.

Comment: What do you mean by badge-family? I'm seeing them both under the moderation heading.

Comment: @Dom I just mean like closely related badges based on varying levels of the same type of interaction - [shown here](http://i.imgur.com/uYrE8ee.png).

Comment: It may just be a way to get users to learn to vote... the carrot on a stick. But I see your point @apex You **can't** get Vox Populi unless you also get Suffrage.

Comment: @Scott I think Dom is right, my question's link goes to the [meta badges](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/badges), but there is a separate page for [GDSE badges](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/badges), where you are listed as having Vox Populi

Comment: This sounds like something you should put on meta.StackExchange, not here as it's a system wide thing. Also, it shouldn't be gold because anyone can get it by throwing votes around without purpose in one day. Keeping it as a bronze gives less incentive to do so

Comment: That might be it @Zach - considering how easy it would be to just brute-force achieve those badges, maybe they aren't in the same family (as I'm calling it) just so they can both be bronze.

Comment: On thinking about it, you do make a decent point, if you include all voting badges, there might be enough to make a 'Voting Badges' category.

Comment: Also, looks like this might answer your question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228091/why-do-we-need-both-the-suffrage-and-vox-populi-badges?lq=1

Comment: Indeed it does @Dom, pretty much makes my question a duplicate.