# About vox-populi badge

Tags: support, badges, voting

I have voted for 40 [Questions + Answers] , I got warning about daily limit and now I am not able to do new vote as its limit reached but in my **Profile Activity** it shows 37 out of 40 [37/40], Why? and still I did not get vox-populi badge.

Comment: Could it be caching? If you were going for that badge, did you happen to check whether each vote was "immediately" reflected via that counter? Badges aren't guaranteed until 24 hours after the event (although they're generally much quicker), so that's my guess, if it's telling you that you aren't allowed to vote any more.

Comment: I have checked by clear cache , ok let me wait for 24 hours then....

Comment: It's more likely server-side caching. But yeah, no, I have no idea. Hopefully someone else will have more experience with this particular badge's behavior--each one tends to behave a little differently.

Comment: To be able to reach 40 votes, you need to have cast at least 10 votes on questions. Did you do that? (Otherwise your vote limit will be lower.)

Comment: @Mat - Really do not remember that , I have voted for questions but do not know for how many...but then why it is not specified in badge description?

Comment: @HelpingHands: each badge description isn't going to list all the details and rules. You get a fuller description [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) though that does mention this.

Comment: @HelpingHands, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254598/248268 for TL;DR of how to get this badge. The profile activity doesn't lie, while the counter shown in "Next badge" takes some minutes to update.

Comment: If you think that the current system is silly, click [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238680/255554).