# "Vox Populi" vote tallying might not be working on The Workplace

Tags: support, badges, voting

I joined The Workplace a few days ago to learn more about professional courtesy and have been reading a lot each day. I've been upvoting a lot of genuinely useful Q/As and (*I'm pretty sure*) hitting the 40-vote daily maximum for the past three days.

[image: What I see when trying to vote right now]

What's curious to me is that I haven't yet received the "Vox Populi" badge. When I look at my profile right now, for example, I see it stuck at 37/40 votes. The same is visible in the "Votes" profile section.

[image]

Am I misunderstanding something about how the vote-counting works, or did I find a genuine bug? I've noticed that comment votes don't show up in the "Votes" profile section... is this why?

Comment: You only get 30 votes per day by default. However, if you vote on questions enough in a day, you get "additional" votes, up to 10. You only get Vox Populi if you cast all 40 of these votes. I'm guessing you aren't voting on questions enough to get the full 10 votes

Comment: Ah, okay. Now that you mention it, I realize that this Q/A (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90479/272056) answers my question.