# I have reached the daily vote limit... and I'm now over it by one. Why?

Tags: discussion, vote-count, voting-limits

I have a strange issue. I reached my daily vote limit a while ago. I keep reading and editing and answering, and sometimes I just can't help but clicking an answer.

Typically [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310579/in-filename-not-as-a-dir-seperator/), my answer was wrong, and I voted up the other answer when I noticed it. I got the "daily limit" message, but the vote still got in. I may have done it elsewhere actually, since I just realized this.

- Is it a browser bug? (as in, what the browser shows is not the reality)
- Is it a SO bug? (as in, the database actually has now inadequate information)

Comment: Your daily vote limit (and the resulting message) is achieved on your last vote, not the one prior.

Comment: Yes. I already got it at least twice. However, I may have an explanation, it seems one post I downvoted has been deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, note that you get up to 40 votes per day. This is a relatively recent change; for a long time, the limit was 30. You still get a maximum of 30 votes if you don't vote on enough questions. See the [voting limits FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits) for details.

As you've noticed, if a post that you voted on is deleted, you get the corresponding vote back. So you can vote more than 40 times a day that way, although only 40 end up mattering.
As far as I know, there's an edge case where you can have more than 40 votes that matter in a day, if a post that you voted on is undeleted.

The [Suffrage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/118/suffrage) and [Vox Populi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/147/vox-populi) badges are awarded at the end of the day. [They take deleted posts into account.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117846/votes-cast-should-include-votes-on-deleted-contributions)

You can keep track of the number of times you've voted today in the popup that appears when you hover on your user name in the top bar, or in your profile.

Comment: Well, I already have the badges, I was just wondering about the reason for the limit-overtake. Now I'm a happy monkey again :p