# Stackoverflow flagging limits

Tags: support, flags, comment-flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)

I was curious about flagging on SO.  I went to flag a comment and it said i had 5 left.  Is that 5 per day, week or forever?  Also, do users with more rep get more flags?

Comment: @Bob (edited comment)- maybe not quite a dupe as it talks about comment flagging where as the title isn't comment specific, just the example of a comment. page also has conflicting information with the FAQ

Comment: @davidsleeps I still feel that this question is adequately answered by our existing FAQ questions.

Comment: @Bob agreed (as evidenced by the fact that my answer is a link and excerpt from the FAQ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Are there any voting limits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5212/141346) which contains this section related to flagging:

> - At 15 or more reputation, at least 5 spam/offensive flag votes per day per user
>
>   - One additional spam/offensive flag vote per 2000 reputation or 20 flag-weight, to a maximum of 100 spam/offensive votes
> - At 10k reputation, at least 5 delete votes per day per user
>
>   - One additional delete vote per 1000 reputation, to a maximum of 30 delete votes
> - At least 10 general moderator flag votes per day per user with 15 or more reputation.
>
>   - One additional general moderator flag vote per every 1k of reputation or 20 flag-weight, up to a maximum of 100.