# Does undoing a downvote reverse the one reputation point loss?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

If I downvote accidentally, or downvote first and later realize that it's not worth downvoting and undo the downvote, do I get back the 1 reputation point lost because of downvoting?

Comment: I downvoted you post to test. I didn't lose any reputation though its weird.

Comment: The answer to the question is yes.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk down-votes on questions do not cost any rep.

Comment: @Rory Oh thanks I didn't know that ..

Comment: @Rory I didnt know that either.. thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you get the 1 reputation back. Undownvoting in all senses is literally a *reversal of the original downvote*. Meaning all reputation effects of the downvote are also reversed.

Comment: @juergen said that voting is locked after 5 minutes.. can you confirm that as well?

Comment: That is true, but the system will tell you whether or not you can retract a vote (when you attempt to do so). I don't know what post you're talking about so I can't tell you whether your vote is currently locked or not.

Comment: got it. I was talking in general. not specific to a Q.

Comment: @lordlupine See [are there any voting limits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits)

Answer (score 0):

After 5 minutes your vote is locked. You can't change it unless the post got edited. Then you can change your vote.

But this should really really not just be because of that 1 rep point you lost (Besides you only lose one point for downvoting answers and not for questions).