# Banned from reviewing but can vote to close if the post already has a vote on it

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, vote-to-close, review-suspension

I am currently banned from reviewing for failing audits.

I just had a post which I wanted to flag as too broad. I noticed that it already had `close(1)` next to the `flag` link. I went and flagged the post and it actually registered my flag as a vote - now it's showing `close(2)`.

The post in question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240076/c-sharp-project-in-cloud.

Does it mean there's a bug which allowed me to review even though I'm currently banned?

Sorry if it's a duplicate, couldn't find a similar bug report.

Comment: If you are not on the review panel, **you are not reviewing**. That simple, nothing more to be said about that. As for your "flag" being registered as a vote - users with vote-to-close privileges cannot flag for closure; the flags get automatically converted to actual close votes. A review ban does not take away your normal site privileges; it *only* blocks you from reviewing.

Comment: @animuson is there somewhere explaining the rationale behind that? If you aren't going to trust someone to review (ergo the ban, be it close votes, or suggested edits), why would you trust them to close/edit normally?

Comment: @jmac Because naturally running across things, you're much more likely to judge it appropriately. Reviewing is a fast-paced environment and the review ban is there to prevent users from abusing the privileges they've been granted via robo-reviewing. If you're abusing your privileges *outside* the review panel, a conversation with a moderator and/or full-out suspension would be more appropriate.

Comment: @animuson thanks for the response. I am amazed that there are that many people who robo-review and then use their privileges for good normally. Boggles the mind.

Comment: It seems I unmasked myself as robo-reviewer by asking this question ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Closing a question from the post page != review. If you are banned from review that doesn't mean you are not allowed to vote to close a question. Review is different thing. So it's not a bug. It is by design.

Comment: His flag registered as vote. Isn't that a bug? Unless someone else close voted that question at the same time.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra - He didn't flag. He just voted to close. If you have 3K+ reputation and still click on flag to close, the popup will redirect you to a close vote popup.

Comment: Yes, I just got over 3k rep.

Comment: @hims056 okay got it. +1 for u

Comment: Is it possible for someone with enough rep to close-vote, to get banned from close voting (not necessarily through the review)?

Comment: @user1271772: Not particularly banned but [there is a limit in casting close/reopen votes per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/187824).