# Stackoverflow Up vote counting time 14 hours

Tags: support, review, voting, time-limit

This is my 1st post in "[Meta Stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)". I notice that in "[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)" the daily **"up vote"** limit is 40, and if a user complete his daily limit, the next 40 **"up vote"** will start after 14 hours. Here i want to say that, i know "[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)" maintain his time according **"UTC time"**. But my question is if a person complete his daily limit, does the count down start just after finishing his task or it regulated by fixed **"UTC time"**? Hope you understand my question.

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: @senshin yeah, it seems to me like duplicate too. Should i delete this question now?

Comment: No need to delete duplicate questions - leaving them around makes it easier for future visitors to find what they're looking for.

Comment: You can't, because it has an up voted answer. Moreover, you accepted it.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for commenting, Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daily limits get reset at midnight GMT. The countdown to reset the limit does not depend on when the user reached his/her daily limit.

> The Stack Exchange network defines a "day" by the UTC/GMT clock. New days start at 00:00:00 UTC/GMT.

[What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I got it.