# How do I retract a "leave open" vote for closure?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-reopen

I fat-moused the "leave open" button for a question that should have been closed.

[How can the complexity of this function be decreased?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917507/how-can-the-complexity-of-this-function-be-decreased)

How do I change this to a close vote, or at least retract my vote?

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes

Comment: The answer provided in the other question does relate to this post (which I now understand after the fact), but I never would have found it under that title.  How can we improve the ability to find that question and answer?

Comment: You have to search with a few different keywords and different phrases to find relevant previously asked things. The search doesn't just find things in titles, or exact title matches. So while you might search "retract" and the dupe is "revoke" with the correct and enough relevant keywords you should have come across something useful, even if it lead to a trail of dupes eventually to one that helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Review actions can't be retracted - your Leave Open response will always be there. Choosing Leave Open only records that action for the review item, and will only affect anything if two other people also choose Leave Open. It doesn't record any actual "vote" on the question.

If you realize you made a mistake, you can always just visit the question. There you can cast an actual vote to close, or you can retract your vote to close (if you had voted to close from review). This will not, however, change your action for the review item.

Answer (score 2):

By 'leave open', I guess you mean that you did this in a review queue.

If you did, you can just go to the question and vote to close the question - what you did in the review queue will not stop you from closing the question outside of it.

But the history in the review queue won't change from 'leave open' - but at least you still did the right thing (in the end!)