# Vox Populi is impossible

Tags: support, voting-badges

Right now, I have 0 votes left on PPCG.

[image]

However, `Vox Populi` says I have voted `33` times.

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: Most likely, you voted on too many answers.  See [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/300411)

Comment: You could have voted less than 40 times - it is not certainly a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not a bug. You may cast 30 votes per day, but you can get some bonus votes if you  vote on *questions* - up to a maximum of 10 extra votes, so that makes 40. You can only earn these bonus votes if the 'countdown' (x votes left for today) hasn't started yet.