# Recast vote after question closed as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, locked-votes

I met [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973484/why-void-between-two-comma-separated-statements-in-a-for-loop/43973565?noredirect=1#comment74977402_43973565) question and thought: "gee what a nice question and great answers too" and gave it an upvote.

Then it got closed as duplicate.

But by then I can no longer recast my vote. Is this intentional?

To clarify, I mean to ask is this somewhat counter intuitive vote casting behaviour intentional, as in "is there logic behind this?", not for the rules of recasting.

Am I required to search for possible problems of the question before I cast my vote, even though it looks perfectly fine?

Comment: So what if it is a duplicate? It doesn't mean it's a bad question. IMO upvote shouldn't be removed just because of that.

Comment: Indeed, but it inadvertently promotes or rather doesn't dissuade people from posting before searching

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes)

Comment: Before I lol at the irony, I want to point out this is asking specifically if not being able recast votes after a question closed is intentional, as it is somewhat counter intuitive.

Comment: Agree it's not a dupe, it's not asking "how", but "why?" which is different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you first voted for the question as it was a *nice* question and had *nice* answers, you used your vote correctly: the question was clear and nicely written. But now, after seeing that it's a duplicate and wanting to retract the vote *just* because it is a duplicate isn't doing the question justice.

Reading Jeff's blog about the [types of duplicates and their handling](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/29/handling-duplicate-questions/) gives a good idea about the types of duplicate. The article also hints that not *all* duplicates are bad.

Doing some homework before casting a vote, in my opinion, is always a good thing to do. If not for duplicates atleast make sure that it isn't:

- Primarily opinion based.
- Off-topic.
- Too broad.

Then, do a quick check for duplicates, perhaps in the sidebar, using the site-search and using google. If you find it quickly *and* the question has good answers, vote to close the question as an duplicate. If it has bad answers, you can wait for new answers and vote to close the original question as an duplicate.

However if the duplicate was too hard to find, and for some reason you couldn't find it even after thoroughly searching and someone else later points out in the comments that it *is* a duplicate, upvote the question. You now have a better coverage and a greater chance of new users finding the question.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is intentional that once you've voted, and the content hasn't changed, you can't retract your vote. A good question wouldn't turn into a bad question over night you know.

The problem here is that you think duplicates are bad. And indeed, they are bad when it is the 1000th time the same question was asked and the new question doesn't show any effort of the OP to search for those duplicates at all.

However, not every duplicate is necessarily bad. Sometimes the duplicate is hard to find because of the specific keywords used. Sometimes it needs quite some knowledge to know it is actually a duplicate of another question.

If the question itself is fine, it is well-written, shows the OP has done their part on researching an answer, than there is nothing but an upvote it deserves, and an answer though the duplicate of course.