# What is "You have 5 votes left today" message?

Tags: discussion, up-votes, voting-limits

When I was doing upvote to an answer/question, I encountered the following message:

> You have 5 votes left today

What's that?

I think I've too voted-up today.

Comment: It's like with the handrolling cigarette paper boxes. One day or another you'll see a green sheet telling you _You have 5 papers left_.

Comment: If you mean you already reached that limit at the same day before, there are conditions you may get extra votes within half an hour.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  my question updated

Comment: That's not nice and invalidates my answer. _too much_ is still fine and left in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I found what is this message, this was such as a stack, when I voted to an answer appear this message `You have 5 votes left today` then I up-voted to another answer and appear `You have 4 votes left today`.

Comment: _@Ben_ Regarding that you're right. It's not like the cigarette paper boxes really, there are no green leafs for every piece of the last 5.

Comment: Already answered in the FAQ here: [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes)

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I searching this question before it, but not appear any result, so then I think this question maybe is useful for other persons with new **key-words**.

Comment: Great, it seems like you understand the purpose of keeping duplicates. However, it's considered better practice to simply edit the keywords into the FAQ instead. They are marked community wiki so that other users can more easily make edits. Posting a duplicate comes across as not doing enough research and can thus lead to downvotes.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I thought that a duplicated question must be deleted, and I occasionally scolded with this subject.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where were you "scolded"?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog Do you mean to send the link?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312312/does-setting-an-accepted-flag-on-a-question-have-a-reputation

Comment: Well, I don't see any scolding there (or the comments in question were deleted). By the way, downvotes on your posts don't mean anything personal; they're just helping to categorize your question. See: [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying) and [this answer to How does Meta Stack Exchange work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47646/377214).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ You sure picked an extremely obscure analogy there.

Comment: @curiousdannii Well known enough among smokers :3

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ As I said, extremely obscure!

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> You have 5 votes left today
> ```
>
> What's this?
>
> I think today had been more upvotes!

You are parsing that message wrong. It doesn't mean the number of votes you left so far<sup>1</sup>, but the additional (left to you) numbers of votes for the rest of the day.

It's just a nice hint from the system regarding your voting behavior.

---

As for your edit:

> I think I have up-voted too much today.

As I mentioned in a comment. *too much* is completely left to the eye of the beholder.

The system simply shows you a count down of leftover votes for the day, because they have a daily limit, you wouldn't notice otherwise.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>This would have been: `You left x votes today`</sub>

Comment: update quote in your answer

Comment: @BenyaminJafari Why so? I'd need to rewrite a number of parts then accordingly.

Comment: because I updated my question in order to better express my problem

Comment: @Ben I picked it up.

Comment: @Ben _"because I updated my question"_ Isn't really a reason to urge me to do things, mkay?