# Daily reviews doesn't match votes available. Why is that?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

What's the difference between "your daily reviews" and the "votes left today" in the review queues?

Here's a visual from [SO](//stackoverflow.com)'s [close vote queue](//stackoverflow.com/review/close) where you can cast 40 close votes (within the queue) within a day:

[image]

Below is a visual for [TeX.SE](//tex.stackexchange.com)'s [close vote queue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/close) where you can cast 20 close votes (within the queue) within a day:

[image]

Possibly there is an incentive to still perform some reviews (like closure) outside of the specific review queue even if you've reached or daily limit. Is this the case? Or is this a bug?

Comment: You can still cast close votes without going into the review queue, and the number of close votes you have per day is independent from the number of reviews you can do per day

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cast votes outside of the queue. This is done from the close button under any open question when browsing normally and doesn’t count as a review.

You might, for example, Close 4 questions in the TeX Close queue and Leave Open 16, using up all your Close queue reviews for the day, and still have [20 close votes remaining](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/323179) that you can use outside the queue (including on questions in the First Posts queue).

The same is true for flags, but with different numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Most SE sites allow users with the Cast Close & Reopen Votes privilege to cast 24 close *votes* per day. [This is the case on TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions). This corresponds to the total number of posts you can vote to close in one day, including in reviews and outside of reviews.

Unless the Close Votes review queue is overflowing, you can perform up to 20 close vote *reviews* per day. This is not the number of posts you can vote to close; this is the number of reviews you can perform in the review queue. If any review queue is overflowing (meaning the number of posts in the queue exceeds a certain threshold), your daily limit is increased to 40 *while the queue is overflowing*; this limit returns to 20 when it is no longer overflowing.

On Stack Overflow, [users can cast up to 50 close votes every day](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) rather than 24 like most sites. Additionally, the Close Votes queue has been overflowing for a very long time (as of writing this answer there are almost 4800 posts in the queue), increasing the maximum daily CV reviews to 40, unless/until a miracle occurs and the queue stops overflowing.

Completing a Close Votes review only uses up a close vote if you select the Close option; Edit, Leave Open, and Skip do not result in using up a close vote. Casting a close vote outside a review queue does not affect your daily review count. Thus, it is very possible to use up your daily reviews and still have close votes remaining, or use up your daily close votes before completing the maximum number of daily reviews.